# Stacking select columns as rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have `df_in` below:

```py
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'A': [1, 0, 0], 'B': [1, 1, 0]})
```

`df_in`:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   | X | A | B |
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | c | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to achieve something like the following:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'Y': ['A', 'B', 'B']})
```

`df_out`:

```
+---+---+---+
|   | X | Y |
+---+---+---+
| 0 | a | A |
| 1 | a | B |
| 2 | b | B |
+---+---+---+
```

I also have a list containing the columns: `l = list(['A', 'B'])`. The logic is, for each column in `df_in` that is in `l`, repeat those observations where the column value `== 1`, and add the column name to a new column in `df_out`, this is `Y` in the example. In reality there are more columns in `df_in` and not all of them are in `l`, which is why I want to solve this without explicit references to columns `A`, `B` and `X`.

**NOTE**: This is not entirely covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607740/reverse-a-get-dummies-encoding-in-pandas) since, as stated above, there are many columns in reality, and these can be of any type and data, so the solution, `df_out`, needs to take into account all of the original columns (`X` in this case). In theory, `X` can also be a binary `0/1` column, but should only affect the outcome in the same way as `A` and `B` if it's included in `l`. I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Question was originally asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166869/reshape-multiple-columns-into-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all columns without `l` pass to [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), filter only `1` and last convert [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) to new `DataFrame` with `rename` last column:

```
l = ['A', 'B']

c = df_in.columns.difference(l, sort=False).tolist()
s = df_in.set_index(c).stack()
df_out = s[s == 1].index.to_frame(index=False).rename(columns={len(c):'Y'})
print (df_out)
   X  Y
0  a  A
1  a  B
2  b  B
```