# Creating more simple lines from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Movie        Action    Adventure    Duration Director   More info...
SpongeBob       0          1           123      Karl
The Avengers    1          1           134      Annie
```

But I want to split that up into lines containing only the movie, one genre at a time and some more columns, like 'Director' and 'Duration'. After the transformation, the DataFrame should look like this:

```
Movie            Genre       Duration Director  (No more extra info)
SpongeBob      Adventure        123      Karl
The Avengers   Adventure        134      Annie
The Avengers   Action           134      Annie
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607740/reverse-a-get-dummies-encoding-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
df.melt(['Movie', 'Duration', 'Director', 'More info'], var_name='Genre')\
  .query('value == 1')\
  .drop('value', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
          Movie  Duration Director More info      Genre
1  The Avengers       134    Annie         B     Action
2     SpongeBob       123     Karl         A  Adventure
3  The Avengers       134    Annie         B  Adventure
```

Reshape the dataframe using `melt` then filter for rows where value equals to 1, then drop the value column.