# Reverse get_dummies()

Tags: pandas, categorical-data

My dataframe looks like this after converting categorical to numerical using `get_dummies()`

```
score1 score2  country_CN country _AU category_leader category_
0.89.   0.45.   0.         1.            0              1
0.55.   0.54     1.        0             1              0
```

As you can see the converted categorical to numerical columns are `country_CN country _AU category_leader category_`

I want to bring it to its's original dataframe something like this:

```
score1 score2  country category_leader 
0.89.   0.45.   AU                    
0.55.   0.54    CN            leader
```

I have tried using the suggestion listed here: [Reverse a get_dummies encoding in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607740/reverse-a-get-dummies-encoding-in-pandas)

But no luck as of yet.

Any help/ clue?

Comment: Do you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62085741/2901002) ?

Comment: Ok, so comment solution failed for you?

Comment: Yes cant make it work both the links..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert for dummies columns to index first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/62085741/2901002
df = undummify(df.set_index(['score1','score2'])).reset_index()
```

Or use alternative solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), fiter rows with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), splitting by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and last pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.melt(['score1','score2'])
df1 = df1[df1['value'].eq(1)]
df1[['a','b']] = df1.pop('variable').str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.pivot(index=['score1','score2'], columns='a', values='b').reset_index()
print (df1)
a  score1  score2 category country
0    0.55    0.54   leader      CN
1    0.89    0.45               AU
```